# Channel messaging on HTML 5 with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem with the messaging channel in HTML 5
On one side I have the code:

```
<iframe id="ifr" src="receive.html" onLoad="initMessaging()" ></iframe>
<button onClick="postMsg()">Wyslij</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
 var channel = new MessageChannel();

channel.port1.onmessage = function (evt) {
    alert(evt.origin + ": " + evt.data);
 };

 function initMessaging() {
     var child = document.getElementById("ifr");
     child.contentWindow.postMessage('hello', 'http://localhost:85', [channel.port2]);
 }

 function postMsg() {
     channel.port1.postMessage('Message sent from ' + location.host);
 }
```

And on second site:

```
     <input type="button" value="Post Message"  onClick="postMsg();" />


<script type="text/javascript">
var port = null;
window.addEventListener("message", function (e) {
    port = e.ports[0];
    port.onmessage = function (e){
    port.addEventListener("message", function (evt) {alert("Received message \"" + evt.data + "\" from domain: " + evt.origin);
     }, false);
 }
}, false);


 function postMsg() {
 if(port) {
     port.postMessage("Data sent from " + location.host);
 }
```

Why Its doesnt working? What I do wrong?

Thx a lot for help!

Comment: What is the MessageChannel object you're instantiating? The demos I see don't require that. Also, I just noticed that according to the W3 spec your port.postMessage call should read as port.source.postMessage?

Comment: I created this code based on information from the <http://dev.w3.org/html5/postmsg/>
When in place postMessage.('hello', 'http://localhost:85', [channel.port2]) give postMessage ('hello', 'http://localhost:85') so this is a question of problems with the channel.

Comment: Yeah I dug a little deeper and saw that. I'm looking to see what I can find. It's an interesting problem since I may have to use this for a project.

Comment: I don't see you calling the port's start method to open it. Did you just leave that out?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use a form to call the postMessage function and send the message. [Here's a tutorial](http://robertnyman.com/2010/03/18/postmessage-in-html5-to-send-messages-between-windows-and-iframes/) that shows a simpler way of getting this done.

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 postMessage interface is not good. I propose an intuitive one. you can download it  from my site:
http://www.jackiszhp.info/tech/postMSG.html

window.MSG.post(msgname, msgdata, arrayOfDomainTarget, arrayOfWindowIDTarget)

this 'window' can be omit, not similar to the one specified in HTML5
there you need an window object.
Here, you do not. this 'window' just indicate MSG is in the global space.

msgname is the the name the message category.
msgdata is a JSON object. it will be stringified before post
arrayOfDomainTarget, arrayOfWindowIDTarget
        I use logical AND. originally it was OR
        later I changed it to AND. more appropriate. I guess.
        and I let "*" to be the wildcard for all windowID.

the caller's information does not present in the parameter at all
 since the browser knows all the information.
so we can see that this method does not allow the sender to fool the receiver.

the sender just call as follows.

```
window.name="myWindowID";
MSG.post("cmd",{what:'do thing abc',parameter:'the value of a parameter'},["jackiszhp.info"],[*]);
```

for the receiver, 2 things.

```
//#1 define the message handler
function messageHandler(e){
var obj=JSON.parse(e.detail);
obj.name is the msgname = 'cmd'
obj.data is the msgdata = {what:'fuck',who:'not to tell'};
obj.source  is the sender
obj.source.href  is the sender's window.location.href
obj.source.WID  is the sender's window.name="myWindowID";
obj.target  is the target of this event
obj.target.domains  is the target domains of this event
obj.target.WIDs  is the target WIDs of this event
....
}
//#2 register the message handler
window.addEventListener(msgname, messageHandler,false);
or
document.addEventListener(msgname, messageHandler,false);

//to respond, 
window.name="hereMywindowID";
MSG.post("cmd",{what:'do thing def',parameter:'the value of a parameter'},["jackiszhp.info"],['myWindowID']);

//clearly, we can see that this response only the original sender can receive it.
//unless in the target domain, accidently, there are two windows with same ID "myWindowID".
```

Additional note:

## A. window can be uniquely identified. but here, I did not use it. I use window.name  instead. about window ID, you can check this link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Code_snippets/Windows#Uniquely_identifying_DOM_windows

## B. I hope the mozilla can take my interface and include it into the firefox.